# Is there something special that you need to do when moving ionic 4 project from PC to Mac?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I began developing my ionic 4 application on my Windows 10 PC and my app is working well on the PC and I can even sideload it onto my Android device.

I installed ionic on my macbook air (latest version) and moved the code over but it fails to compile - at least, using ionic lab. No real error messages… just the fail to compile.

Is there something I need to do to make the same code work on a macbook?

I tried re-installing ionic but nothing seems to work.

Too much code to post

I would expect it to just work since it's the same code base and this is supposed to be cross platform.

Comment: did you follow this guide: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/platform-setup/mac-setup.html

Comment: What do you mean by fail to compile? Can you post the error message here? I have found that different operating systems use different node_modules to build. So try deleting node_modules and running ```npm install``` again. There is a plugin called node-sass which needs to be rebuilded when moving from Windows to a UNIX based system or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't done anything much as far as setup goes. You haven't given the logs either. So there is only a guess I can make, which is that you haven't set your system up right.

There are many steps which need to be followed at the start of Ionic development:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cli
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/environment
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/ios
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/running
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios

Follow all of these in detail and then see if things work for you.